# Allow shop manager to use revolution slider

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, revolution-slider

Which attribute shall I insert to this function in order to allow the shop manager to use the revolution slider plugin?
I tried this code but it doesn't work!

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    $role = get_role( 'shop_manager' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_rev_slider' ); 

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use anymore this kind of tricks with Revolution slider, because it handle this himself.

You need to go in the **global settings** of this plugin (a little button in top right when you are on main Revolution Slider backend page) and change the authorized user roles from **`Admin`** to **`Editor, Admin`** or **`Author, Editor, Admin`**.

This way the  **`Shop Manager`** user role will have access to Revolution Slider settings.